# How to access a function from the library class file in the magento2 custom controller

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I was trying to create an extension for redis in magento 2.For that i was trying  to call getTag() function from magento2 Redis.php `lib\internal\cm\cache\backend\Redis.php` in my custom controller.

Let me know how can i access the function from the library class `lib\internal\cm\cache\backend\Redis.php` in my custom controller. Can anyone show me some examples of accessing a library function in the magento2 custom controller.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can call it directly

```
$obj = new \Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis($options = array());
$obj->getTag();
```

You need to specify the options.